# How to pick the child nodes value on a web page using selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

this is my webpage which i need to automate. the values next to the checkbox are dynamic. they are not constant. So i would like to choose one of this option and when i hit the search button the matching search result will be displayed for me. Please help.

[image: HTML DOM Code and Screen which needs to be automated]

[image: Bigger version]

Comment: could you please upload a larger version of your screenshot, it is unreadable?

Comment: Hope this helps. have updated above here

Comment: You can try this //*[@class='Advancesearch' and @value='4']/span

Comment: but these are dynamic controls. for instance in the screen shor above it has 9 check boxes. but there can be instance when there will be only 2 or there can be 15. So in this case do you think using the value will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a fan of xpath but I think it's your best bet.
Try the following:

Collect all the spans under the accordion-contrent like so:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='rms-accordion-content']/label/span")
```

Then iterate over the list and filter out all elements with data-bind attribute text: Name

Hope this helps.
Good luck!

Comment: I havent tried this yet, got held up with something. but how do we iterate on this

Comment: @homewrecker- thank you so much. i cracked this out. 

here is what i did 

 List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='rms-accordion-content']/label/span"));
   Iterator<WebElement> i = elements.iterator();
     while(i.hasNext()) {
         WebElement row = i.next();
         System.out.println(row.getText());
     }

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='rms-accordion-content']/label/span")); Iterator i = elements.iterator(); while(i.hasNext()) { WebElement row = i.next(); System.out.println(row.getText()); }

this is what i used

Answer (score -1):

Below code will display all the checkboxes names
**Note:** code is in C#

```
IWebElement ModelElement = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("rms-accordion-content"));
IList<IWebElement> LabelEle = ModelElement.FindElements(By.TagName("label"));
for(int i =0; i < LabelEle.Count; i++)
{
     Console.WriteLine(LabelEle.Text);
}
```

Comment: This might not help me because, i dont want to select all the checkboxes. my requirement is that i dont know in my run time how many check box options will come because that varies. first i need to get the list or count of what are available and then choose to tick one or many.
can you help on this

Comment: @gayathrisanthanagopalan Changed code to display all the labels, so how are you going to decide which element should be clicked in runtime ??

Comment: i am thinking of collecting all the labels first and print them so i know what are the available options i have. secondly, 2 scenarios to verify
1. choose all the available options and click on search
2. choose the first one and click on search.

Comment: thank you so much. i got the labels printed. refer above please i got the data

Comment: @gayathrisanthanagopalan mark some something as answer